# Google Fonts & Safari SELECT problem

Tags: html, css, webkit, safari

I have a problem with select when I import fonts from Google Fonts. When I click on select on Safari, website reloads. On Chrome, FF, IE everything is ok. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/stcvS/

Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of safari you using? What OS? Mines running fine on Safari 5.0.5 on Win 7

Comment: Safari 5.1 (6534.50); MAC OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 2):

You can target Safari via CSS and avoid the problem:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

/* for Safari 5.1 bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025826/google-fonts-safari-select-problem */

.formData SELECT {

    font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if JQuery is a route you want to go down, but perhaps this could help:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option>kiko</option>
        <option>atletico</option>
    </select>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#dropdown").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Safari 5.1. Every SELECT with CSS @font-face fails with page reload.

Comment: Same thing happening in my experience

Answer (score 0):

It's better to user `<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>` and apply necessary css and javascript insted of using `<select></select>` in this type of special case where we have to apply different font-familiy , font-style, etc.